# how to hide TwebBrowser Component

Tags: delphi, hide, delphi-7, twebbrowser

hello i am making one app.. "sorry for me bad english";

simple app hay have 2 TWebBrowser on delphi 7 this make simple mi life on mi work
wb1 firts webbrowser run on proxy
wb2 secons webbrowser no run on proxy

i need hide app... i don't have problem with this

```
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  Left := 0;
  Top := 0;
  Width := 0;
  Height := 0;
  Visible := False;
  Application.Title := '';
  Application.ShowMainForm := False;
```

this cool all ok...

i have problem later the app sayme error invalid html document
any can help me thx

Comment: Could you post some of the code around where you get the error?

Comment: the code no have error.. the app on hide sayme invalid html document... i dont know for wath

Comment: Call WebBrowser1.HandleNeeded; before navigating to an address.

Comment: twebbrowser is GUI component. on hide this no work fine any can say other method to i can implemente navigate on the net? windows service for sample?

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `Silent := True`. 
It won't show you any TWebBrowser's message.